# What's the easiest way to render a 2D shape in an A-Frame scene?

Tags: aframe

Say, a shape of a human outline.

Ideally it could be converted to 3d by extruding, but even if it has no depth, that's fine for my use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be taking a transparent `png` image (the human outline), and use it as a source for an `a-plane`

```
<a-plane material="src: img.png; transparent: true"></a-plane>
```

Glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~aframe-png).

....but if you want to create a geometry with a custom shape, which will be helpful for extrusion, then check this out:

### Creating a simple shape with the underlying THREE.js

First you need an array of 2D points:

```
let points = [];
points.push(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0));
// and so on for as many as you want
```

Create a `THREE.Shape` object which vertices will be created from the array

```
var shape = new THREE.Shape(points);
```

Create a mesh with the shape geometry, and any material, and add it to the scene, or entity

```
var geometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(shape);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00
});

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
entity.object3D.add(mesh);
```

More on:
1) [THREE.Shape](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/core/Shape)
2) [THREE.ShapeGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry)
3) [THREE.Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh)

---

### Extrusion

Instead of the `ShapeGeometry` you can use the `ExtrudeGeometry` object:

```
var extrudedGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, {amount: 5, bevelEnabled: false});
```

Where the amount is basically the "thickness". More on `Three.ExtrudeGeometry` [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ExtrudeGeometry).

---

### Usage with AFRAME

I'd recommend creating an `AFRAME` custom component:

*js*

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
    init: function() {
       // mesh creation
       this.el.object3D.add(mesh);
    }
})
```

*HTML*

```
<a-entity foo></a-entity>
```

2D shape [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8h3brjv1/).
Extruded 2D shape [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qtLk2d3u/).
Three.js examples [here](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_shapes). They are quite more complicated than my polygons :)

Answer (score 0):

There are also a couple of pre-built A-Frame components you could use to help with extrusion.

https://github.com/JosePedroDias/aframe-extrude-and-lathe

https://github.com/luiguild/aframe-svg-extruder

You can find examples of usage in each of those repos.