# How to add depth to <a-triangle> in A-Frame

Tags: three.js, aframe, webxr

I tried to get a 3D triangle in the A-Frame framework. However, I couldn't find a way to add depth to it, it is 3D.

I tried adding depth via the geometry depth component

`<a-triangle vertex-c="1 -1 0" depth="2"></a-triangle>`

I also tried to group a box and triangle
`<a-entity position="0 0 0"> <a-box depth="0.1" width="2" height="2" color="#6173F6"></a-box> <a-triangle vertex-a="-1 1 0.05" vertex-b="-1 -1 0.05" vertex-c="1 0 0.05" color="#6173F6"></a-triangle> </a-entity>`

And I tried to scale the triangle

`<a-triangle vertex-c="1 -1 0" scale="1 1 2"></a-triangle>`

Comment: I'd try creating a custom geometry and extruding it like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44968918/add-polygon-in-a-frame) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028045/whats-the-easiest-way-to-render-a-2d-shape-in-an-a-frame-scene)

Comment: Alright, so there is no way to do that without diving into THREE.js?